# Не определяется member в функции on_raw_reaction_remove(), не могу удалить реакцию с сообщения. Пробовал разные варианты, энивей в member выдает None

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

```
@client.event        
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):  
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 767815076455120896:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
                
        if payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")        
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="...")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)
                    
        if role is not None:
            member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id) #на этом месте переменная не определяется
            print(member)                              #соответственно, весь последующий код уже не робит
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                print('[SUCCESS] {0} role was deleted from {1}!' .format(role, member))
        else:
            member = payload.member
            print('[ERROR] Deleting role not found to {0}!' .format(member))
```

P.S. полазив по форумам, уже попробовал включить PRESENCE INTENT и SERVER MEMBERS INTENT в настройках бота на Discord Developer Portal, не помогло :(

Comment: Вам нужно не только включить PRESENCE INTENT и SERVER MEMBERS INTENT в настройках бота на Discord Developer Portal, а и это самое в самом коде бота.

Comment: большое спасибо, ваш код `member = await (await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)).fetch_member(payload.user_id)` помог)) 4 дня не мог найти ничего что сработало бы)